# Export/import/sync iphone data app with Google Docs - where to begin?

Tags: iphone, xml, database, synchronization, google-docs

I have an app which saves some data on a sqlite DB. Basically, I have some notes (textual data) with other info associated with them (tags, date, etc.).

I would export/import these data to/from a **Google Docs** account or sync them with it.
Where to begin? Have you some suggestions/links?

Moreover, is there a way to hold these relations between a note with its other attributes? Maybe with xml?

Thank you,

Fran

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few thing I would do

See some tutorials or code for SQLite, Web Service, Google API's

Design Server and Local database to support for the Sync.

Check Google API's and integration with iPhone SDK some [tutorial](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/)